# SP2010: How to hide/alter default text in a view that has zero item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list-view

How can I alter or hide the text that is displayed in a list view that has zero item -

*There are no items to show in this view of the  list. To add a new item, click "New".*

Note: I'm looking for a JS/CSS based solution as I don't have access to SPD.

Regards,
Korak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

**Using CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
​​td.ms-vb{
   display:none!important;
}
</style>​​​​​​​
```

**Using jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".ms-vb").css("display","none");
});
```

Edit :

Other way out is you have to keep this in a css file. and add its reference to master page. Since default css is not allowing it to override, you have to explicitly specify that your css needs to be applied after default.

```
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration name=”<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Custom Style/css/custom.css %>" After=”corev4.css” runat=”server”/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm gonna add a reference to the CSS file on the master page without using SPD which I don't have access to.

Comment: try jquery code added in answer

Comment: glad it helped :)